# Multiple tables in SAS using where statement

Tags: sas

I am trying to get a table in the following format, which summarises the number of events observed up to a specified timepoint:

```
Timepoint  GroupA  GroupB
le 30        n       n
le 90        n       n
le 180       n       n
le 365       n       n
```

where the data is time to event data with the columns `group`, `tte` and `event` (1 for event). For example:

```
group  tte  event
A      20    0
B      40    0
A      60    1
B      80    0
A      100   1
B      120   1
```

Effectively I am trying to tabulate the number of events occurring at or before specified timepoints.

I can get each row individually using:

```
proc freq data = have;
    tables event * group/ nopercent nocol norow;
    where tte le 30 and event eq 1;
run;

proc freq data = have;
    tables event * group/ nopercent nocol norow;
    where tte le 60 and event eq 1;
run;
```

But is there a way to do this a bit more efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

Just count them.  Merge in the list of TTE cutoff points so you know which counts to write out.

```
data have ;
  input group $ tte event;
cards;
A      20    0
B      40    0
A      60    1
B      80    0
A      100   1
B      120   1
;

data cutoffs;
  do tte=30,90,180,365 ;
    output;
  end;
run;

data want;
  merge have cutoffs(in=in2);
  by tte ;
  if event then do;
    if group='A' then A+1;
    else if group='B' then B+1;
  end;
  if last.tte and in2 then output;
  keep tte a b ;
run;
```

Results

```
Obs    tte    A    B

 1      30    0    0
 2      90    1    0
 3     180    2    1
 4     365    2    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Multi label format.

```
proc format;
value time_group (multilabel)

0 - 30 = '<30'
0 - 60 = '<60'
0 - 180 = '<180'
0 - 365 = '<365'
other = 'Outside Time Period';
run;

data have;
input group $  tte  event;
cards;
A      20    0
B      40    0
A      60    1
B      80    0
A      100   1
B      120   1
;;;;
run;


proc tabulate data=have;
where event=1;
class tte /mlf;
class group;
format tte time_group.;
table tte, group='' *N='';
run;
```